# Link to reference ShareLaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing, sharelatex

I use this to cite References:

> \cite{art1}

And to declare:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References} \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}
@ARTICLE{art1,
  author = {Prof C Sam Charles Devanand},
  title = {Importance of Electronic Document/Information Management Systems
in Modern Architectural, Engineering and Construction Projects},
  year = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents*}
```

How can I put a hyperlink to click on `[1]` and go to the page where said:

```
[1] Importance of Electronic Document/Information Management Systems in Modern Architectural 2002, Prof C Sam Charles Devanand
```

Comment: So you want a link from the text where the citation appears (i.e. `[1]`) to the References list?

Comment: Yes it is that what i want

Comment: Are you using `natbib`? Please add your preamble.

Comment: No i'm not using any package only what i put above

Comment: I cannot test since I don't have a MWE of your document, but try adding this to your preamble (it requires the `hyperref` package): `\hypersetup{backref=true}`.

Comment: Done, you can put with answer :) I put correct. Thanks!!!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following option, which requires you to load the `hyperref` package.

```
\hypersetup{
    backref=true
}
```

You can also add these options, for color:

```
citecolor={...},
linkcolor={...}, 
urlcolor={...},
```

Comment: @PRVS No problem! Glad to help.